# Sum of Column Values in Table - Rdlc report

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, rdlc

I have a Table in Rdlc report with 6 Columns and a dataset. A dll is added ( referenced ) to the Report, named RepHlpr.dll. This dll have a shared function *GetPar* which calculates and gets data from other databases. Column *Amount* is working fine and getting data as per the expression, As :

[image: Expression Value of Column]

While getting Sum of *Copper* and *HP*, Everything Works fine because these column gets values from dataset.

I am getting problem to get Sum of Values of *Amount*. I have tried Expressions :

```
=Sum(Textbox44.Value)
=Sum(ReportItems!Textbox44.Value)
=Sum(Table1.Textbox44.Value)
```

[image: Sum Of Amount Column]

But Its showing Error : Textbox48 ( in which above expression is coded ) uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers. 
**Is there any way to get Sum of Column *Amount* ?**

Comment: Do you need =Sum(Fields!Amount.Value, "DataSet1")?

Comment: There is no Field Name AMOUNT

Comment: Amount Column Get Values According to HP and Make,  of 3 phase motor. I dont have the Coding of RepHlpr.dll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply Sum on your formula of that textbox instead of trying to apply it on the value of textbox:

```
=Sum(Code.YourMethod(Fields!Filed1.Value, Fields!Filed2, otherParam), "YourDataSetName")
```

For example if name of your report data set is `"DataSet1"`

```
Sum(RepHlpr.RepHlpr.GetPar("Amt", Fields!hp.Value, Fields!make.Value), "DataSet1")
```

**Example**

I created a `Code` function:

```
Public Function Multiply(ByVal value As Integer, factor As Integer) As Integer
    Return value * factor
End Function
```

Then I set expression for my extra column that is not data bound:

```
=Code.Multiply(Fields!Price.Value, 2)
```

Then I added a `TextBox` and set its `Sum` expression based on my custom column expression:

```
=Sum(Code.Multiply(Fields!Price.Value, 2), "DataSet1")
```

And here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: why we can't do something like this 
 =Sum(ReportItems!Textbox44.Value) ?

Comment: I think because`Textbox44` is not a member of Your `DataSet1` and probably these aggregate functions only works on fields of your dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on table click insert row->outside group -below 
Right click on column that you want to take sum go to expression.
In category select common function->aggregate then double click on sum in item, now double click select fields (dataset1) in values double click on columns that you want to take sum. Now at the top.
    =Sum(cdec(Fields!salary.Value))
In it salary is the column name in database. But cdec add manually.