# Sum total in RDLC with filtered string

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I have that table:

```
DATE       |  TIME    | DIAL  |  CALL TYPE  |     CALLED  | DURATION | CHARGE
01/01/2015 | 00:13:12 | 49771 | CEL - Globe | 09063561177 | 00:02:42 | 12.60
01/30/2015 | 23:29:21 | 49771 | CEL - Globe | 09178287737 | 00:02:04 | 12.60
01/05/2015 | 19:50:08 | 49771 | CEL - Globe | 09178287737 | 00:02:16 | 12.60
01/04/2015 | 22:00:18 | 49771 | CEL - Globe | 09178287737 | 00:09:05 | 42.00
                                                            Total Php 124.00
```

My question is, how can I get the total cel calls, total idd calls, and total ndd calls separately with one another? I mean:

```
Summary Report:
Total Cell Calls: Php 20.00  
Total NDD Calls: Php 20.00  
Total IDD Calls: Php 84.00  
Total Calls: Php 124.00  
Vat 12%:    14.89  
Total: Php 138.88
```

I've tried this code:

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!cdr_call_type_code.Value="CEL",Fields!cdr_charge_amount.Value,0))
```

But it did not work.

Comment: what did you tried till now?

Comment: I tried this:
=SUM(IIf(Fields!cdr_call_type_code.Value="CEL",Fields!cdr_charge_amount.Value,0)) ----but it did not work :(

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: how can I get the total cel calls, total idd calls, and total ndd calls separately with one another?

Comment: @LyraOpena could you edit your question with what you've tried?

Comment: I've edited it already. :) @kamaci

Comment: in RDLC create a Cell with expression, look here : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/sum-of-a-column-values-in-reports-automatically-using-expres/

Comment: or you cam use : RunningValue(Fields!CHARGE.Value, Sum, Nothing) , read more : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251660%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: also read this and you will know all about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188077/sum-of-column-values-in-table-rdlc-report