# How to sum two timespan fields in RDLC

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer, timespan

If I have two fields of type `System.TimeSpan` like this :

```
Fields!OverTimeBefore6.Value

Fields!OverTimeAfter6.Value
```

---

How to sum these fields together in **RDLC** and the result in same format like this:

```
03:04:17
```

---

Note: I want to sum two or multiple fields not the total of a specific field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of Column Values in Table - Rdlc report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188077/sum-of-column-values-in-table-rdlc-report)

Comment: @fruggiero No it’s not a duplicate, all questions talk about the total values of specific column, i want to sum two different fields!

Comment: Try checking following links for your answer?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21842539/4302116 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504020/4302116

Comment: @ViKiNG Thanks but my question is about `RDLC` not `SQL SERVER`

Comment: Good luck dear. I've about 10 years of reporting experience and due to SSRS limitations, always tried to sort calculation type of things on the server side and mostly used RDLC for presentation. But hope you'll get your answer soon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.Add(...)` function of a Timespan.

That is, if you have a textbox in your report you could set the expression to be:

```
=System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100).Add(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200))
```

and the format to Default, and see the text:

```
00:05:00
```