# I am trying to create an RDLC Report in C# with multiple SQL Queries. Is this possible? I've included a picture with the Layout I am trying to create

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdlc

[image]

Basically every text box/tablinx is associated with a SQL Query

First text box Ship quantity

```
  private SampleData GetData()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "Select sum(ship_qty) from dbo.salesorders";

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
```

Second Text box Ship value
string query = "Select sum(ship_value) from dbo.salesorders";

Third Text box Order value
string query = "Select sum(order_value) from dbo.salesorders";

Fourth Text Box Total Order quantity
string query = "Select sum(order_quantity) from dbo.salesorders";

I've added the table dbo.salesorders to the Dataset as a Table Adapter. when I run build and run the application I don't get any values in the tablinx(I've only tried the first tablinx so far)

But when I change th Query to "Select ship_qty" from dbo.salesorders I'm getting all the values for that column. I don't want all the values I just need the sum.

Any ideas if this layout is possible to implement?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a stored procedure which contains multiple SQL queries and that stored procedure bind to that particular RDLC report.

Comment: Can I bind a query to a specific table/tablinx/text box? For the first query when select sum(qty_shipped) does not fetch any results but select qty_shipped is getting all the results. I just need the sum.

Comment: Use Sum function in RDLC report
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49361135/7300644