# Unable to get total field in report viewer c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am using rdlc report viewer in my pos project. My problem is that when i click on print preview button rdlc report viewer appears all the fields are showing except one field which is total field i dont know where i am doing something wrong.. I am fedup looking for error but got nothing.
Here my code for loadReport in report viewer:

```
 ReportDataSource rptDS;

                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\Reports\Report2.rdlc";
                this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

                DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

                con.Open();
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select c.id, c.transno, c.pcode, p.pname, c.price, c.qty, c.disc, c.total from tblcart as c inner join tblproduct as p on c.pcode = p.pcode where status like 'Sold' and sdate between '" + frm.dt1.Value + "' and '" + frm.dt2.Value + "'", con);
                da.Fill(ds.Tables["dtSoldItemReport"]);
                con.Close();

                rptDS = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables["dtSoldItemReport"]);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptDS);
                reportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
                reportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent;
                reportViewer1.ZoomPercent = 100;x
```

I have a dataset called dtSoldItemReport in which i add above fields. Now in report viewver all the fields are showing except total.

Please help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188077/sum-of-column-values-in-table-rdlc-report

Comment: I dont get it